# Excel VBA - How to Redim a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

In Excel via Visual Basic, I am iterating through a CSV file of invoices that is loaded into Excel. The invoices are in a determinable pattern by client.

I am reading them into a dynamic 2D array, then writing them to another worksheet with older invoices. I understand that I have to reverse rows and columns since only the last dimension of an array may be Redimmed, then transpose when I write it to the master worksheet.

Somewhere, I have the syntax wrong. It keeps telling me that I have already Dimensionalized the array. Somehow did I create it as a static array? What do I need to fix in order to let it operate dynamically?

**WORKING CODE PER ANSWER GIVEN**

```
Sub InvoicesUpdate()
'
'Application Settings
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Instantiate control variables
Dim allRows As Long, currentOffset As Long, invoiceActive As Boolean, mAllRows As Long
Dim iAllRows As Long, unusedRow As Long, row As Long, mWSExists As Boolean, newmAllRows As Long

'Instantiate invoice variables
Dim accountNum As String, custName As String, vinNum As String, caseNum As String, statusField As String
Dim invDate As String, makeField As String, feeDesc As String, amountField As String, invNum As String

'Instantiate Workbook variables
Dim mWB As Workbook 'master
Dim iWB As Workbook 'import

'Instantiate Worksheet variables
Dim mWS As Worksheet
Dim iWS As Worksheet

'Instantiate Range variables
Dim iData As Range

'Initialize variables
invoiceActive = False
row = 0

'Open import workbook
Workbooks.Open ("path:excel_invoices.csv")
Set iWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set iWS = iWB.Sheets("excel_invoices.csv")
iWS.Activate
Range("A1").Select
iAllRows = iWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Count rows of import data

'Instantiate array, include extra column for client name
Dim invoices()
ReDim invoices(10, 0) 

'Loop through rows.
Do

    'Check for the start of a client and store client name
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Account Number" Then

        clientName = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 6).Value

    End If

    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value <> Empty And ActiveCell.Value <> "Account Number" And ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0) = Empty Then

        invoiceActive = True

        'Populate account information.
        accountNum = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
        vinNum = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        'leave out customer name for FDCPA reasons
        caseNum = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        statusField = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        invDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
        makeField = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value

    End If

    If invoiceActive = True And ActiveCell.Value = Empty And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Empty And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = Empty Then

        'Make sure something other than $0 was invoiced
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value <> 0 Then

            'Populate individual item values.
            feeDesc = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
            amountField = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
            invNum = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value

            'Transfer data to array
            invoices(0, row) = "=TODAY()"
            invoices(1, row) = accountNum
            invoices(2, row) = clientName
            invoices(3, row) = vinNum
            invoices(4, row) = caseNum
            invoices(5, row) = statusField
            invoices(6, row) = invDate
            invoices(7, row) = makeField
            invoices(8, row) = feeDesc
            invoices(9, row) = amountField
            invoices(10, row) = invNum

            'Increment row counter for array
            row = row + 1

            'Resize array for next entry
            ReDim Preserve invoices(10,row)

         End If

    End If

    'Find the end of an invoice
    If invoiceActive = True And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9) <> Empty Then

        'Set the flag to outside of an invoice
        invoiceActive = False

    End If

    'Increment active cell to next cell down
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

'Define end of the loop at the last used row
Loop Until ActiveCell.row = iAllRows

'Close import data file
iWB.Close
```

Comment: Why not using `invoices = Range("A1").CurrentRegion` instead of looping ??? Also, all those `Select` and `ActiveCell` are slow and can easily be avoided.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This isn't exactly intuitive, but you cannot Redim[(VB6 Ref)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266231%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) an array if you dimmed it with dimensions. Exact quote from linked page is:

> The ReDim statement is used to size or resize a dynamic array that has
>   already been formally declared using a Private, Public, or Dim
>   statement with **empty parentheses** (without dimension subscripts).

In other words, instead of `dim invoices(10,0)`

You should use

```
Dim invoices()
Redim invoices(10,0)
```

Then when you ReDim, you'll need to use `Redim Preserve (10,row)`

Warning: When Redimensioning multi-dimensional arrays, if you want to preserve your values, you can only increase the last dimension. I.E. `Redim Preserve (11,row)` or even `(11,0)` would fail.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up some confusion for me. This is the first time I am using arrays in VB.

Answer (score 19):

I stumbled across this question while hitting this road block myself. I ended up writing a piece of code real quick to handle this `ReDim Preserve` on a new sized array (first or last dimension). Maybe it will help others who face the same issue.

So for the usage, lets say you have your array originally set as  `MyArray(3,5)`, and you want to make the dimensions (first too!) larger, lets just say to `MyArray(10,20)`. You would be used to doing something like this right?

```
 ReDim Preserve MyArray(10,20) '<-- Returns Error
```

But unfortunately that returns an error because you tried to change the size of the first dimension.  So with my function, you would just do something like this instead:

```
 MyArray = ReDimPreserve(MyArray,10,20)
```

Now the array is larger, and the data is preserved. Your `ReDim Preserve` for a Multi-Dimension array is complete. :)

And last but not least, the miraculous function: `ReDimPreserve()`

```
'redim preserve both dimensions for a multidimension array *ONLY
Public Function ReDimPreserve(aArrayToPreserve,nNewFirstUBound,nNewLastUBound)
    ReDimPreserve = False
    'check if its in array first
    If IsArray(aArrayToPreserve) Then       
        'create new array
        ReDim aPreservedArray(nNewFirstUBound,nNewLastUBound)
        'get old lBound/uBound
        nOldFirstUBound = uBound(aArrayToPreserve,1)
        nOldLastUBound = uBound(aArrayToPreserve,2)         
        'loop through first
        For nFirst = lBound(aArrayToPreserve,1) to nNewFirstUBound
            For nLast = lBound(aArrayToPreserve,2) to nNewLastUBound
                'if its in range, then append to new array the same way
                If nOldFirstUBound >= nFirst And nOldLastUBound >= nLast Then
                    aPreservedArray(nFirst,nLast) = aArrayToPreserve(nFirst,nLast)
                End If
            Next
        Next            
        'return the array redimmed
        If IsArray(aPreservedArray) Then ReDimPreserve = aPreservedArray
    End If
End Function
```

I wrote this in like 20 minutes, so there's no guarantees. But if you would like to use or extend it, feel free.  I would've thought that someone would've had some code like this up here already, well apparently not. So here ya go fellow gearheads.

Comment: Looks like a nice solution. I will try to add this to my code as well. Hopefully it isn't too performance killing as I intend to use this within a loop.

Comment: This worked for me. However keep in mind that this function does not declare any variables, and therefore its arrays are declared as `Variants`. So make sure the array you want to `ReDim` is also declared as `Variant`, or you declare the variables of the function so that they match the declaration type of your arrays.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a bit old but I think there might be a much simpler solution that requires no additional coding:

Instead of transposing, redimming and transposing again, and if we talk about a two dimensional array, why not just store the values transposed to begin with. In that case redim preserve actually increases the right (second) dimension from the start. Or in other words, to visualise it, why not store in two rows instead of two columns if only the nr of columns can be increased with redim preserve.

the indexes would than be 00-01, 01-11, 02-12, 03-13, 04-14, 05-15 ... 0 25-1 25 etcetera instead of 00-01, 10-11, 20-21, 30-31, 40-41 etcetera.

As only the second (or last) dimension can be preserved while redimming, one could maybe argue that this is how arrays are supposed to be used to begin with.
I have not seen this solution anywhere so maybe I'm overlooking something?

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question explicitly, it provides a more efficient solution to the overall problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

here is updated code of the redim preseve method with variabel declaration, hope @Control Freak is fine with it:)

```
Option explicit
'redim preserve both dimensions for a multidimension array *ONLY
Public Function ReDimPreserve(aArrayToPreserve As Variant, nNewFirstUBound As Variant, nNewLastUBound As Variant) As Variant
    Dim nFirst As Long
    Dim nLast As Long
    Dim nOldFirstUBound As Long
    Dim nOldLastUBound As Long

    ReDimPreserve = False
    'check if its in array first
    If IsArray(aArrayToPreserve) Then
        'create new array
        ReDim aPreservedArray(nNewFirstUBound, nNewLastUBound)
        'get old lBound/uBound
        nOldFirstUBound = UBound(aArrayToPreserve, 1)
        nOldLastUBound = UBound(aArrayToPreserve, 2)
        'loop through first
        For nFirst = LBound(aArrayToPreserve, 1) To nNewFirstUBound
            For nLast = LBound(aArrayToPreserve, 2) To nNewLastUBound
                'if its in range, then append to new array the same way
                If nOldFirstUBound >= nFirst And nOldLastUBound >= nLast Then
                    aPreservedArray(nFirst, nLast) = aArrayToPreserve(nFirst, nLast)
                End If
            Next
        Next
        'return the array redimmed
        If IsArray(aPreservedArray) Then ReDimPreserve = aPreservedArray
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

Here ya go.

```vb
Public Function ReDimPreserve(ByRef Arr, ByVal idx1 As Integer, ByVal idx2 As Integer)

    Dim newArr()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    ReDim newArr(idx1, idx2)

    For x = 0 To UBound(Arr, 1)
        For y = 0 To UBound(Arr, 2)
            newArr(x, y) = Arr(x, y)
        Next
    Next

    Arr = newArr

End Function
```

Comment: in my case with some minor changes does work. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do this.

```
Dim TAV() As Variant
Dim ArrayToPreserve() as Variant

TAV = ArrayToPreserve
ReDim ArrayToPreserve(nDim1, nDim2)
For i = 0 To UBound(TAV, 1)
    For j = 0 To UBound(TAV, 2)
        ArrayToPreserve(i, j) = TAV(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

A small update to what @control freak and @skatun wrote previously (sorry I don't have enough reputation to just make a comment). I used skatun's code and it worked well for me except that it was creating a larger array than what I needed. Therefore, I changed:

```
ReDim aPreservedArray(nNewFirstUBound, nNewLastUBound)
```

to:

```
ReDim aPreservedArray(LBound(aArrayToPreserve, 1) To nNewFirstUBound, LBound(aArrayToPreserve, 2) To nNewLastUBound)
```

This will maintain whatever the original array's lower bounds were (either 0, 1, or whatever; the original code assumes 0) for both dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this in a shorter fashion.

```
Dim marray() as variant, array2() as variant, YY ,ZZ as integer
YY=1
ZZ=1

Redim marray(1 to 1000, 1 to 10)
Do while ZZ<100 ' this is populating the first array
marray(ZZ,YY)= "something"
ZZ=ZZ+1
YY=YY+1 
Loop
'this part is where you store your array in another then resize and restore to original
array2= marray
Redim marray(1 to ZZ-1, 1 to YY)
marray = array2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this `array(0)= array(0,1,2,3)`.

```
Sub add_new(data_array() As Variant, new_data() As Variant)
    Dim ar2() As Variant, fl As Integer
    If Not (isEmpty(data_array)) = True Then
        fl = 0
    Else
        fl = UBound(data_array) + 1
    End If
    ReDim Preserve data_array(fl)
    data_array(fl) = new_data
End Sub

Sub demo()
    Dim dt() As Variant, nw(0, 1) As Variant
    nw(0, 0) = "Hi"
    nw(0, 1) = "Bye"
    Call add_new(dt, nw)
    nw(0, 0) = "Good"
    nw(0, 1) = "Bad"
    Call add_new(dt, nw)
End Sub
```