# Issue regarding the upper index number of an array when using Redim Preserve Statement at VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, preserve

Just a quick question on VBA Arrays...

What happens if I use the `ReDim Preserve` statement and I resize an Array by decreasing the Upper index number. If `myArray(5) ="Shmoo"` what if I do that:

```
ReDim Preserve myArray(2)
```

Can it be done since the `Preserve` must not loose the data that are tied to each index number in the array and index number 5 in the array has the String value "Smoo" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - Run-time error '9', Subscript out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667785/excel-vba-run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data in `myArray(3)`, `myArray(4)` and `myArray(5)` will be lost. `Preserve` only keeps the data that fits within the new size specified with the `ReDim` statement.

From the Excel VBA help file:

`If you make an array smaller than it was, data in the eliminated elements will be lost.`

Comment: Thank you so much you are a life saver! I really wanted to know this!

Comment: No problem! You can close the question by clicking the checkmark beside the answer, if you found it helpful... :)