# Redimensioning both dimensions of a multi-dimensional array in VBA (why a solution here won't work)

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

Firstly, I will point out that the question around redimensioning a multi-dimensional array has been discussed and answered here: [Excel VBA - How to Redim a 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183775/excel-vba-how-to-redim-a-2d-array).

My issue is that I am trying to apply this answer and it isn't quite going smoothly! The issue is with calling the Function. If I dimension the array before calling the function, Excel just tells me it can't assign to the array (presumably because I'm not telling it which element to assign to). If I don't dimension the array beforehand then the function falls apart when it is looking for the dimensions of the old array...because it doesn't have any, presumably.

I know I can do the below by reversing the way round the array builds and then transposing it but I have need further on to change both dimensions of the array so am trying to get it working here first.

I will admit I'm at 'losing the will to live' stage with this code as I have been battling it for weeks and am an amateur wannabe programmer, so I realise it might be a really simple answer but I can't see it at the moment. Any help gratefully received.

Here's my code (the Sub is called from another sub, where all other variables are defined)

```
Sub CalculateRank(row, coln, TempSums, TempProducts, Lead_count)
Dim Maj As Double
Dim CompareCount As Integer
Dim CompareArray(1, 1) '**I don't really want to dimension this array before the loop below.

Maj = WorksheetFunction.Round(Range("FJudges") / 2, 0)


For coln = 1 To Lead_count
    CompareCount = 0
    For row = 1 To Lead_count
        If TempSums(row, coln) >= Maj Then
            CompareCount = CompareCount + 1
            CompareArray = ReDimPreserve(CompareArray, CompareCount, 3) '**This is the line that is calling the function (copied directly from the bottom of the page linked above) and giving the error
            CompareArray(CompareCount, 1) = row 
            CompareArray(CompareCount, 2) = TempSums(row, coln) 
            CompareArray(CompareCount, 3) = TempProducts(row, coln) 
        End If
    Next row
Next coln
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to make it a 2D array before calling that function, **but** with a `Redim` statement instead of `Dim`. The problem is not in the function `ReDimPreserve` you're using, because it takes an input array and returns another one from scratch. Your problem is in the assignment statement:

> ```
> CompareArray = ...
> ```

VBA does not permit assigning to a *static array*, which is the case because you declared it as:

> ```
> Dim CompareArray(1, 1)
> ```

You need instead to declare it as a *dynamic array*, like this:

```
Dim CompareArray()           ' <--- Optional declaration
ReDim CompareArray(0, 0)     ' <--- First initialization should be with ReDim
```

p.s.

- The declaration `Dim CompareArray()` is optional, but is considered by many as good practice. Basically you can omit it and declare directly using `ReDim` (even with `Option Explicit`). Just make sure no other variable with the same name exists in the same scope (which the compiler would alert about if the `Dim` statement is there).
- I started with `(0, 0)` because this is the minimal size, instead of `(1, 1)` (EDIT: unless you are using `Option Base 1` as it appeared in the comment).

Comment: You need to open your own `VBPedia` ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado I need to get the golden tag first ;)

Comment: I knew I was just being dense. Thank you. Although, Redim CompareArray(0,0) throws up an error, but (1,1) is fine. Is that because I have set 'Option Base 1'?

Comment: @EventDani yes, certainly!